# Access to any element of a table

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have built a table in a stored procedure :

```
declare @storeTable table
(
path varchar(1000) not null,
nbdays int,
offset int
)

insert @storeTable
select PATH, NUMBER, OFFSET  from
FILENAME f left outer join ...
```

Let's say that my table have 4 rows, like this:

```
Path1 | 3 | 1
Path2 | 9 | -1
Path3 | 2 | 3
Path4 | 5 | 0
```

I would like to know how I can have access to any element from this table.

For instance, I would like to use the value -1 of the offset on the row 2, in order to include it at the end of the Path2 (and thus modify the path2)

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a variable what I do is to create a temp table. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#storeTable] (
[path] varchar(1000) not null,
    [nbdays] int,
    [offset] int
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Then you can do select or joins/updates with your regular tables. Temp table is deleted when you exist SP. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

Select path+cast(offset as varchar) as path
From @storeTable